# How Iron Router renders single page web app, compared to Angularjs and Backbonejs

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, routes, single-page-application, iron-router

As Iron Router introduction in https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router,

> Iron Router is a routing package for Meteor. It makes single page apps.

However, I don't understand how it works.

In Angularjs or Backbonejs, each route contains a hashtag, for example
 example.com/#about
 example.com/#service

I can understand that this is just one page example.com. The hashtag indicates that although there are two different URLs, both of them are still example.com but at different states. If we navigate from example.com/#about to example.com/#service, we are still in the same page which is example.com and only part of the layout is changed.

In Iron Router, the routes do not contain hashtag, for ex
example.com/about
example.com/service

To me, the two URLs represent two totally different states. If we navigate from example.com/about to example.com/service, we have to refresh the page and load new page from the beginning.

So the question is How Iron Router renders single page web app, what is its mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Building a single page application without a hashtag needs some routing rules implemented at web server level. Not sure how Iron Router does it, but if

example.com/about

example.com/service

pointing to same page, there should be some routing on server which says, route example.com/* to index.html or some thing like that. Also Single Page Applications without hashtag has some compatibility issues in older IE browsers, keep a tab on that.

Comment: When I inspected element, went to the network tab, cleared all existing network requests, then traversed between /about page and homepage, nothing happened in the network tab, but the page content and the urls were changed. Check out [this clip](http://recordit.co/AynynEeNQJ)

Comment: how are you navigating between these 2 pages? using back button?

Comment: well if you are on a browser which supports pushState you can avoid it making requests to server (the way it's working for you). but you need a route config to avoid 404 when user directly lands in "example.com/about" you need a server side route which redirects it to index.html. Once request comes to index.html, backbone can take over from there and display about us page for you.

Comment: I clicked on the page links, e.g. home and about buttons. You can check here [http://velocitytesting.meteor.com/](http://velocitytesting.meteor.com/)

Comment: it's using push state as I said in my last comment